# vim python navigate to imported files

Tags: python, vim, ctags

who is this question may seem silly, but I'm stuck. 
I write gnuradio application in some python file.
In VIM I try to open a file that is imported, for example:

```
from gnuradio import audio
```

Let's say I use the function:

```
audio.sink()
```

It is possible in vim to quickly get content of

```
sink()
```

function? In the manner of command CTRL-] of ctags.

P.s. using Ctags navigation to `audio.sink()` return me error: `tag not found: sink`. Using Ctags i can navigate only to local definitions ( not imported ). I check

ctags --list-kinds=python

import option is enabled.
Inside `tags` file i see:

```
audio   fm_receiver.py  /^from gnuradio import audio$/;"    i
```

Comment: Ctags should let you jump to a definition anywhere in the project. What version are you using, and how are you invoking it?

Comment: I use exuberant ctags version 5.8. Installed with "apt-get" command. Tags file created from command file using "ctags -R". Then in vim targetting to the "tags" file.

Comment: for make it usable i need to create tags file in each used gnuradio directories (/usr/lib/python2.7/.../gnuradio/audio, ... ) and set this all files to "tags" variable in vim. Is there any plugin that let me don't do this by hand ( more comphortable ).

Answer (score 5):

This works fairly quickly, but not exactly like you'd like. You add this line to your .vimrc

```
nnoremap <C-k> :!ctags -aR /usr/lib/python*/site-packages/<cword><cr>
```

Then you can hover over the package name `gnuradio` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to execute the command which will append that packages source files to your local tags file (vim's default as well). Then you can <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> over the `sink` keyword to get the function.

Comment: In my case the file in question is `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webargs/fields.py`. So there can be multiple directories to search in. What should we do in this case?